# Is there a difference in declaring instances of inherited classes in these different ways?

Tags: c++

If I have a class called "Animal", and a derived class "Bird : public Animal", I can create a Bird these two ways:

```
Animal *sparrow = new Bird;
Bird *sparrow = new Bird;
```

Both compile fine and work as expected. Are they equivalent? Should I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line, in itself, doesn't demonstrate the difference. However, assume `Bird` declares a method `Fly` that doesn't exist on `Animal`. You wouldn't be able to do:

```
Animal* a = new Bird;
a->Fly();
```

on the other hand, this is legal:

```
Bird* b = new Bird;
b->Fly();
```

The distinction here is a result of the fact that C++ is a statically typed language. The static type of the variable is what the compiler cares about when it's verifying things like method calls. Since the static type of the variable `a` is `Animal` which doesn't have a `Fly` method, the compiler will not allow you to call `Fly` on it (not all animals are able to fly, so you'll have to explicitly cast to `Bird`: `dynamic_cast<Bird*>(a)->Fly()` is legal).

The expression `new Bird` will have the type `Bird*`. If you assign a value of a derived type to a variable of a based type, the compiler will not complain (all `Bird`s are `Animal`s, so it should always work). Basically, the compiler upcasts `Bird*` to `Animal*`. The reverse is not true. Not all `Animal`s are `Bird`s, so you'll have to take the responsibility and do the cast explicitly and tell the compiler that I know that object is really a `Bird*`. Only in that case the compiler will let you to use `Bird`-specific features. So, in general, if you need to use a `Bird`-specific member, you'd better use `Bird* b = new Bird;`.

Comment: I think I understand. A follow up to clear it in my mind:

Animal *A = new Animal;
Animal *B = new Bird;

With these declarations, is there any difference between A and B? (question asked before some edits above)

Comment: @Jarred: Yes, the object pointed by `A` is not really a `Bird` whereas the object pointed by `B` is still really a `Bird` and you simply decided not to care at the moment that it is (since your function applies to all animals equally and doesn't rely on anything specific to birds). Since `B` is a `Bird`, you can successfully downcast it to `Bird*` again and use `Bird` specific members. Casting `A` to `Bird*` won't succeed.